# SwiftUI The Simplest MVVM

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I tried to build the simplest Model View ViewModel (MVVM) for SwiftUI as a kind of learning exercise. The result is below. My question is: Is this code the shortest mvvm or you could make it even simpler and shorter?

```
// Model

import Foundation

struct SimplestModel <Content> {
   var mItem: String
   init() {mItem = ""}
}

// View Model

import SwiftUI

class Portal {

   private var model : SimplestModel<String> = Portal.setContent()

   static func setContent() -> SimplestModel<String>{
       return SimplestModel<String>.init()
}

func getString() -> String {
    model.mItem = "Portal"
    return model.mItem
  }

}

// View

struct ContentView: View {

  var viewModel: Portal

  var body: some View {
      Text(viewModel.getString())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `ContentView` will not be updated on model (or view model) changed. If you want to completely hide model (and of course still have view refreshed) here is possible approach

Note: I don't see necessity of generics in this case

```
struct SimplestModel {
    var mItem: String = ""
}

// View Model

import SwiftUI

class Portal: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String {
        didSet {
            if name != model.mItem {  // avoid cycling
                model.mItem = name
            }
        }
    }

    private var model: SimplestModel {
        didSet {
            if name != model.mItem {    // avoid cycling
                name = model.mItem
            }
        }
    }

    init(model: SimplestModel = SimplestModel()) {
        self.model = model
        self.name = model.mItem
    }
}

// View

struct DemoContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: Portal

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.name)
    }
}
```